# \sectionformat in Koma classes with babel [spanish]

Tags: koma-script, babel, spanish

I can't modify the `\sectionformat` in KOMA classes when using the *spanish* option in {babel}. Is there any direct fix (I mean, without recurring to {titlesec})?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[%
%   english,
    spanish, % <--- Problem
    ]{babel}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}[1]{Secc. }

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the `es-nosectiondot` option, `babel-spanish` restores the default definition of `\@seccntformat`, so overriding the redefinition made in the KOMA classes.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[spanish,es-nosectiondot]{babel}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{Secc. \thesection\autodot\enskip}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{ABC}

\end{document}
```

[image]