# Custom document structure

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, structure

I would like to typeset regulations and laws in LaTeX. For that I would need a way to structure my document like this:

1. Title
2. Chapter
3. Section
4. [Subsection]
5. Article

Is there any way I can override the sectioning commands that default (or KOMA-Script) classes provide? You can see an example of the structure I would like to achieve here: https://www.boe.es/buscar/pdf/2015/BOE-A-2015-10566-consolidado.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with legalese terminology for sectioning headers, but it sounds like the following correspondence can be made: LaTeX: `part` -- legal: `Title`; `chapter` -- `Chapter`; `section` -- `Section`; [what's with subsections?]; `subsubsection` -- `Article`. Is this interpretation roughly correct?

Comment: Yes! Subsections would be optional and that's why I put them in brackets, but I think it's a bit confusing. I think articles would be something more like paragraphs. The number of the article would be in line with the rest of the text. Still, there would be differences because there's no need for titles to be on different pages ¿like \parts are?. You can see more or less (it's in spanish but) what I would like to achieve on the link.

Comment: Moreover, it would appear that Chapter numbers are reset each time there's a new Title and that Section numbers are reset each time there's a new Chapter. In contrast, the numbering of Articles appears to be ever-increasing throughout the document -- no resets at the start of Sections (or of Titles or Chapters), right?

Comment: Exactly! Article numbers should not reset but Chapter and Sections should.

Comment: If you are happy with the size and formatting for \part, \chapter, \section and \subsection, just use, for example, \renewcommand{\partname}{Ttile} to change the names.  Article will need a separate counter, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using class `scrartcl`:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\newcaptionname{english}{\Titlename}{Title}
\newcaptionname{english}{\Chaptername}{Chapter}
\newcaptionname{english}{\Sectionname}{Section}
\newcaptionname{english}{\Subsectionname}{Subsection}
\newcaptionname{english}{\Articlename}{Article}

\renewcommand\raggedpart{\centering}
\renewcommand\raggedsection{\centering}

\newcommand\entryprefix[2]{%
  #1\ #2
}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=part,
  level=\partnumdepth,
  tocbeforeskip=2.25em plus 1pt,
  tocindent=0pt,
  tocnumwidth=2.3em,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\Titlename}
]{Title}
\renewcommand\theTitle{\Roman{Title}}
\renewcommand\Titleformat{\Titlename~\theTitle\autodot}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=part,
  level=0,
  counterwithin=Title,
  font=\LARGE,
  prefixfont=\Large,
  tocindent=1em,
  tocnumwidth=2.3em,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\Chaptername}
]{Chapter}
\renewcommand\theChapter{\Roman{Chapter}}
\renewcommand\Chapterformat{\Chaptername~\theChapter\autodot}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  counterwithin=Chapter,
  tocentryformat=\normalfont,
  tocbeforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,
  tocentryindent=2em,
  tocpagenumberformat=\normalfont,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\Sectionname},
    toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
]{section}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\Sectionname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentryindent=3em,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\Subsectionname}
]{subsection}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{\Subsectionname~\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=\subsubsectionnumdepth,
  beforeskip=3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
  afterskip= 1.5ex plus .2ex,
  indent=0pt,
  font=\mdseries\slshape,
  tocstyle=default,
  toclevel=\subsubsectiontocdepth,
  tocindent=4em,
  tocnumwidth=2.3em,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\Articlename}
]{Article}
\renewcommand\Articleformat{\Articlename~\theArticle\autodot\enskip}

\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{Article}
    {\raggedright\textbf{\upshape#3}#4.}
    {#3#4}%
}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Title{Title level}
\Chapter{Chapter level}
\section{Section level}
\Article{An article}
\lipsum[1-3]
\Article{A second article}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Section level}
\subsection{A subsection}
\Article{An article}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Another subsection}
\Article{A second article}
\lipsum[4]
\Title{Title level}
\Chapter{Chapter level}
\section{Section level}
\Article{An article}
\lipsum[1-3]
\Article{Another article}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this looks great! However, I tried to reproduce the document with the code you provided and I get some errors, beginning with `! Class scrartcl Error: before part skip of \Title unknown.` and I'm not sure why... There's not much info anywhere on that error. Any idea?

Comment: Which KOMA-Script version do you use? The code in my answer needs at least version 3.24, current version on CTAN and in the TL 2018 and MiKTex is 3.25.

Comment: With versions 3.21, 3.22 or 3.23 you have to add something like `beforeskip=4ex, afterskip=3ex` to the declaration of both `Title` and `Chapter`. Additionally `Title` needs `font=\huge,prefixfont=\Large`. Note that versions 3.24 and 3.25 uses the settings of `part` as default values for new section commands with `style=part`.

Comment: I have version 3.23, maybe I should try to update TexLive. But your workaround works perfectly! Thank you! This is what I wanted! What would be the benefits of using `scrjura`?

Comment: If I change _english_ to _spanish_ on `newcaptionname` and translate the appropiate strings, the word "Article (Artículo in spanish) disappears on every line an article starts. Any ideas?

Comment: Load `babel` with option `es-nosectiondot`:  `\usepackage[spanish,es-nosectiondot]{babel}`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282228/43317

Answer (score 3):

[image: pic of act]

Based on the solution of esdd, I suggest to use the scrjura package for typesetting legal texts. My code is mostly stolen from Elkes solution, I only changed it on the level of Artículo and changed the language, because we have to provide the caption names for Artículos.

```
\documentclass[spanish, juratotoc=true, toc=flat]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{scrjura, libertine}
\newcaptionname{spanish}{\Titlename}{TÍTULO}
\newcaptionname{spanish}{\Chaptername}{CAPÍTULO}
\newcaptionname{spanish}{\Sectionname}{Sección}
\newcaptionname{spanish}{\Subsectionname}{Subsección}
%\newcaptionname{english}{\Articlename}{Article}

\providecaptionname{spanish}{\parname}{Artículo}
\providecaptionname{spanish}{\parshortname}{Art.}

\renewcommand{\Clauseformat}[1]{Artículo~#1.}
\setkomafont{contract.Clause}{\itshape{}}

\renewcommand\raggedpart{\centering}
\renewcommand\raggedsection{\centering}

\newcommand\entryprefix[2]{%
  #1\ #2
}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=part,
  level=\partnumdepth,
  tocbeforeskip=2.25em plus 1pt,
  tocindent=0pt,
  tocnumwidth=2.3em,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\Titlename}
]{Title}
\renewcommand\theTitle{\Roman{Title}}
\renewcommand\Titleformat{\Titlename~\theTitle\autodot}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=part,
  level=0,
  counterwithin=Title,
  font=\LARGE,
  prefixfont=\Large,
  tocindent=1em,
  tocnumwidth=2.3em,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\Chaptername}
]{Chapter}
\renewcommand\theChapter{\Roman{Chapter}}
\renewcommand\Chapterformat{\Chaptername~\theChapter\autodot}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  counterwithin=Chapter,
  tocentryformat=\normalfont,
  tocbeforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,
  tocentryindent=2em,
  tocpagenumberformat=\normalfont,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\Sectionname},
    toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
]{section}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\Sectionname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentryindent=3em,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\Subsectionname}
]{subsection}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{\Subsectionname~\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}

% \DeclareNewSectionCommand[
%   style=section,
%   level=\subsubsectionnumdepth,
%   beforeskip=3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
%   afterskip= 1.5ex plus .2ex,
%   indent=0pt,
%   font=\mdseries\slshape,
%   tocstyle=default,
%   toclevel=\subsubsectiontocdepth,
%   tocindent=4em,
%   tocnumwidth=2.3em,
%   tocdynnumwidth,
%   tocentrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\Articlename}
% ]{Article}
% \renewcommand\Articleformat{\Articlename~\theArticle\autodot\enskip}

% \renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
%   \ifstr{#1}{Article}
%     {\raggedright\textbf{\upshape#3}#4.}
%     {#3#4}%
% }




\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Title{Title level}
\Chapter{Chapter level}
\section{Section level}
\begin{contract}
  \Clause{title=Objeto.}
\label{CLA:objeto}
 La potestad sancionadora de las Administraciones Públicas se ejercerá cuando haya 
 sido  expresamente  reconocida  por  una  norma  con  rango  de  Ley,\dots

  El  ejercicio  de  la  potestad  sancionadora  corresponde\dots

\Clause{title=Ámbito Subjetivo}
\label{CLA:ambito-subjetivo}

Las  disposiciones  de  este  Capítulo  serán  extensivas  al  ejercicio  por  las 
Administraciones Públicas de su potestad disciplinaria

Las  disposiciones  de  este  capítulo  no  serán  de  aplicación  al  ejercicio  por  las 
Administraciones  Públicas  de  la  potestad


\end{contract}

\section{Section level}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{contract}
  \Clause{title=Principios generales}
\label{CLA:principios-generales}

La potestad sancionadora de las Administraciones Públicas se ejercerá cuando haya 
 sido  expresamente  reconocida  por  una  norma  con  rango  de  Ley,\dots

  El  ejercicio  de  la  potestad  sancionadora  corresponde\dots

Las  disposiciones  de  este  Capítulo  serán  extensivas  al  ejercicio  por  las 
Administraciones Públicas de su potestad disciplinaria

Las  disposiciones  de  este  capítulo  no  serán  de  aplicación  al  ejercicio  por  las 
Administraciones  Públicas  de  la  potestad


\Clause{title={Principios de intervención de las Administraciones Públicas para el desarrollo de 
una actividad.}, tocentry={Principios de intervención}}
\label{CLA:titl-de-interv}

La potestad sancionadora de las Administraciones Públicas se ejercerá cuando haya 
 sido  expresamente  reconocida  por  una  norma  con  rango  de  Ley,\dots

  El  ejercicio  de  la  potestad  sancionadora  corresponde\dots

Las  disposiciones  de  este  Capítulo  serán  extensivas  al  ejercicio  por  las 
Administraciones Públicas de su potestad disciplinaria

Las  disposiciones  de  este  capítulo  no  serán  de  aplicación  al  ejercicio  por  las 
Administraciones  Públicas  de  la  potestad




\end{contract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The Artículo numbers in TOC are followed by two dots. You have to disable either `\autodot` for these TOC entries (eg. `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[...,entryformat=\let\autodot\relax]{default}{cpar}`) or the dot in `\Clauseformat` within TOC (eg. `\newcommand*\Clausedot{.}` `\renewcommand{\Clauseformat}[1]{Artículo~#1\Clausedot}` and `\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\renewcommand*\Clausedot\relax}`).

Comment: @esdd Yes, there is plenty room for improvement. I expect OP to ask for changes of the par-counter »(1)« and much more. I did not look into the references according to spanish law and so on. But I'd be glad if he used scrjura for his purposes.

Comment: I also believe that using `scrjura` is very useful here.

Comment: Oh, yeah, this looks really nice too! However I'm having the same problem I told @esdd, `! Class scrartcl Error: before part skip of \Title unknown.`. I don't know if it's I'm copying something wrong (I tried exactly what you typed there), or maybe my LaTeX setup is outdated? I don't know.

Comment: Another question, what are the benefits of using `scrjura`? It sounds interesting... Thanks!